# How do I target a specific key in an array of objects for a conditional inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

New to JS! Trying to specify a statement for one of my keys inside my object, which again is nested in an array. Next to Slowbro - the message: "Wow this is a big Pokemon" should be displayed but this is not working. I am trying to write a general conditional within my for loop for all Pokemons but also specify that the "Wow this is a big Pokemon" message should only appear for Slowbro and not just any who meet the height>1.5 criteria. What did I miss?

```js
//Array contains Pokemon data to display in application
//Each object represents one Pokemon with respective properties
let pokemonList = [
        {name:'Pikachu', height: 0.4, type:['electric','ground','steel','flying']},
        {name:'Charmeleon', height: 1.1, type:['ground','rock', 'water']},
        {name: 'Slowbro' ,height: 1.6, type:['electric', 'grass','dragon','ghost','bug']}
      ];

//Loop lists each Pokemon in array by assigning name and height keys 
for (let i=0; i < pokemonList.length; i++) 
  { document.write(pokemonList[i].name+ ' (height: ' + pokemonList[i].height + ') ' + '<br>')
  }



for (let i=0; i < pokemonList[i].length; i++) {
  if (pokemonList[i].height > 1.5 && pokemonList[i].name === 'Slowbro') {
    console.log('- Wow, this is a big Pokemon!');
    } else if (pokemonList[i].height > 0.5 && pokemonList[i].height < 1.5) {
    console.log('- This is an average size Pokemon.');
    } else {
    console.log('- This is a small Pokemon.')
    }
}
```

Comment: error is here `for (let i=0; i < pokemonList[i].length; i++) {`. should be `for (let i=0; i < pokemonList.length; i++) {` without `[i]`.          and set       `{` after `if (pokemonList[i].height > 1.5 && pokemonList[i].name === 'Slowbro')`

Comment: Despite missing a bracket for the first `if`, the problem is that your for loop should be `(let i=0; i < pokemonList[i].length; i++)`. If you do `pokemonList[i]` you have an object, which have no length.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov That was my bad, thanks! However, the message still does not show next to them. I tried adding this but also without success: console.log(pokemonList[i].name + '- Wow, this is a big Pokemon!');

Comment: @FSDevie, do you want to get this message in the document, or in the console?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Thanks! Just saw it shows in the console of my website (that was my original plan) (although it does not work online in console on replit due to an unexpected identifier "pokemonList" - tested the code though and there are no syntax error so should be fine! Would I just replace console.log with document.write to have it show on the document instead?

Comment: @FSDevie, I would suggest using `innerHTML` instead of `write()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last `for` loop in your code snippet, instead of the length of the array, you are using the length of its first element:

```js
for (let i=0; i < pokemonList[a].length; i++)
```

Where you probably want the length of the array itself:

```js
for (let i=0; i < pokemonList.length; i++)
```

instead.

```js
//Array contains Pokemon data to display in application
//Each object represents one Pokemon with respective properties
let pokemonList = [
        {name:'Pikachu', height: 0.4, type:['electric','ground','steel','flying']},
        {name:'Charmeleon', height: 1.1, type:['ground','rock', 'water']},
        {name: 'Slowbro' ,height: 1.6, type:['electric', 'grass','dragon','ghost','bug']}
      ];

//Loop lists each Pokemon in array by assigning name and height keys 
for (let i=0; i < pokemonList.length; i++) 
  { document.write(pokemonList[i].name+ ' (height: ' + pokemonList[i].height + ') ' + '<br>')
  }



for (let i=0; i < pokemonList.length; i++) {
  if (pokemonList[i].height > 1.5 && pokemonList[i].name === 'Slowbro') {
    console.log('- Wow, this is a big Pokemon!');
    } else if (pokemonList[i].height > 0.5 && pokemonList[i].height < 1.5) {
    console.log('- This is an average size Pokemon.');
    } else {
    console.log('- This is a small Pokemon.')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
//Array contains Pokemon data to display in application
//Each object represents one Pokemon with respective properties
let pokemonList = [
        {name:'Pikachu', height: 0.4, type:['electric','ground','steel','flying']},
        {name:'Charmeleon', height: 1.1, type:['ground','rock', 'water']},
        {name: 'Slowbro' ,height: 1.6, type:['electric', 'grass','dragon','ghost','bug']}
      ];

const html = pokemonList.map(({name, height}) => {
   return `${name} (height: ${height})`
}).join('<br>')

document.write(html)

pokemonList.forEach(({name, height}) => {
  if( height > 1.5){
    console.log('- Wow, this is a big Pokemon!')
  }else if(height > 0.5){
    console.log('- This is an average size Pokemon.');
  } else {
    console.log('- This is a small Pokemon.')
  }
})
```